# How to Use google translate api in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Hi i am working on a small project there actually i got a requirement of implementing the Language Translator my project relates to Hotel billing system so i want to want Translate each and every item to a selected language .

here i want to display the results in data grid  where as in the first column it will display the item name in english when i select auto transilate it has to transilate into the language which i selected  and it has to display in another column in data grid

Comment: Google Translate API is available as a paid service, are you ready for it?

Comment: Oh that i don't know but is there any option ?

Comment: Not only Google offer service like this.

Comment: Bing Translator is there but there is limit for that

Comment: This is very broad question. Do you have a specific question or issue you're running into?